# How to create a column contains words from a string?

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataset with a column(string) containing several titles. If I wanted to do an operation, for example, where I create a new column (colB) doing an operation with [contains](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.contains.html) or [like](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.like.html) (eg `like("%hello%")` ), so that if it had *discounts* in the string it would fill with a ***discount*** in colB or of have *hello* in the string would fill with ***hello*** in colB. And if I had both, I would put them both separated by a comma.

Example of the desired table below

| colA | colB |
| --- | --- |
| Hello World | hello |
| Hi World | null |
| Discounts for apples | discount |
| Check this discount! | discount |
| Hello World and discount! | discount, hello |

How do I go around and create this kind of dataset? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `regex_match`? And you can add them together with `concat`.

Comment: Not with regex_match, i was doing something like this `.withColumn('colB',\ when(col('colA')).like('%hello%'), lit('hello'))` But then, how do I add discount if it appears in the colA it's more my doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`concat_ws`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws) to add your text together

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df
    .withColumn('b', F.concat_ws(', ', F.array(
        F.when(F.lower('a').like('%hello%'), F.lit('hello')),
        F.when(F.lower('a').like('%discount%'), F.lit('discount')),
    )))
    .show(10, False)
)

+-------------------------+---------------+
|a                        |b              |
+-------------------------+---------------+
|Hello World              |hello          |
|Hi World                 |               |
|Discounts for apples     |discount       |
|Check this discount!     |discount       |
|Hello World and discount!|hello, discount|
+-------------------------+---------------+
```